# всплывающий блок рядом с заданным блоком

Tags: javascript, скрипт

Где-то видел или в престе или в другом двиге шаблоны были написаны таким путем что появившийся(всплывающий) клеелся с другим блоком не зависимо от того где он прописан или внизу страницы или другом месте, конкретно вопрос в css есть параметр который добавляет эту манипуляцию.
подскажите кто такое видел потому что немогу найти...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-8XIlIyyoeiwuxFkZ_EBkbzOtvITqMSb/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl  и описание https://geektimes.com/post/52271/

Answer (score 0):

она почемуто конфликтует с кодом что писали до меня вот тут http://test.createzone.kl.com.ua/js/script.js
а конкретно если код ниже удалить проверка работает, но у меня падают всплывающие окна.

```
function send(form,otziv) {
    jform = $(form);
    window.form = form;
    data = jform.serialize() + '&type=' + form.id;

    console.log(data);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/send_email.php',
        beforeSend: lock_button,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            restore_button();
            if (otziv==1) {
                        $('#overlay1').fadeIn(400,
            function () {
                $('#modal_form4')
                    .css('display', 'block')
                    .animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                        top: '35%'
                        }, 200);
                    });
                    }
            else {
                        $('#overlay1').fadeIn(400,
            function () {
                $('#modal_form3')
                    .css('display', 'block')
                    .animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                        top: '35%'
                        }, 200);
                    });
                    };
        },
        type: 'POST',
        data: data
    });
}
```